# Concatenate N arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm working with mongodb and I'm dealing with **aggregate** to join two collections, now I would like to convert my result

```
    "Users" : [ 
        [ 
            "Carl", 
            "John",
            "Ever"
        ], 
        [ 
            "Dani", 
            "GG", 
            "Sussan"
        ],
        .... N arrays

    ]
```

to this output

```
    "Users" : [ 
            "Carl", 
            "John",
            "Ever",
            "Dani", 
            "GG", 
            "Sussan",
            ..... M elements from N arrays 
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- reduce starting from `[]`
- concat each array member to one flatten array

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71225060-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"Users":
   {"$reduce":
    {"input":"$Users",
     "initialValue":[],
     "in":{"$concatArrays":["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks much for your comment, it works!